# Can't see any ads when connecting via one ISP

Tags: web-filtering

I've noticed that I don't see any ads when I connect via one ISP. Browser/OS doesn't matter. When I connect via another ISP I can see ads. What might be causing this filtering? This has been going on for about 2-3 days.

EDIT: When I try pinging any of the ad servers that aren't displaying ads for me I get `Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`... Does that mean my ISP has blocked these ad servers?

Comment: "Does that mean my ISP has blocked these ad servers?" - Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible that the ISP or router is performing "[*DNS Hijacking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking)".

You didn't mention the hostname of the server you tried pinging, but it's likely that the ISP is returning `127.0.0.1` (localhost) for that DNS entry.

Try using `nslookup`, with a known server (e.g: [`8.8.8.8`](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)), and you may well get the correct result.

Comment: `googlesyndication.com` for example - returns `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yup, added the Google DNS and all is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

More and more ISPs block ads for you. For instance, my Internet box (the `Freebox Mini`, by the French ISP `Free`) has a built-in ad blocker, which I can disable in the box's settings. I disabled it and use AdBlock Plus instead, so I can choose *where* I block ads and where I don't.

You should try to see if your own box offers the option to enable or disable the ad blocker, either from the box's settings (usually at `http://X.X.X.1` or `http://X.X.X.254`, where `X.X.X` are the 3 first digit groups of your computer's IP) or from your ISP's account page. If you can't disable it, your ISP is violating the Internet Neutrality.